# everything in viewcontroller disappeared after I return from imagepicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

when I am trying to implement all the uiimagepickerview methods in my app, my view controller (after choosing an image) shows nothing on it? It should have my textfields however they all 'disppeared'

Here's my code

```
@IBAction func registerUserProfileImageSelectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        registerUserProfileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        registerUserProfileImage.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I suspect it may be something to do in my dismiss method, but I am not too certain

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you share demo project?

Comment: What you have written in ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear and viewDidDispapper ?

Comment: you did not assign a delegate to your image picker in your registerUserProfileImageSelectButton method. see my answer @porkchopbento

Comment: Have you set the view controller doing the presenting to be delegate?You have the correct methods for it to work, but without setting the VC *as* the delegate it won't work.

Comment: "dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)"  Dismissing what!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is you are trying to dismiss the current view controller, not the image picker controller. Please use:

```
imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me perfectly you can try this code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePickerImg: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func imagePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self // you need to set a delegate to your image picker here 
        //to get selected ( edited ) portion
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

     public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print(info)

//        let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // if you keep editing true
        let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
        imagePickerImg.image = img
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        print("Cancel Press")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: How does this answer solve whatever problem the OP is having? Explain what was wrong and explain how this code solves that problem.

Comment: check comments @maddy

Comment: Why do you assume the delegate isn't set? Your assumption would be wrong. The question makes it clear that the delegate methods are being called.

Comment: @maddy you try it for yourself then comment here